# Simple function in lua: pick a random parameter passed into it

Tags: math, random, parameters, lua, arguments

i would love to have functionality like this:

```
print(randomParameter(1,2,3))
-- prints 1 2 or 3... randomly picks a parameter
```

i have tried using the func(...) argument but i cant seem to use the table ARG when i pass multiple parameters. I tried this:

```
function hsv(...)
  return arg[math.random(1,#arg)] -- also tried: return arg[math.random(#arg)]
end

print(hsv(5,32,7))
```

i have even tried putting the #arg into a variable using the rand function, also making a for loop with it sequentially adding a variable to count the table. still nothing works.

i remember doing this a while back, amd it looked different then this. can anyone Help with this? THANKS!

Comment: `return (select(math.random(select('#',...)),...))`

Comment: could you explain a bit more? i dont seem to understand, is that the only line in the function?

Comment: Or `local arg={...} return arg[math.random(#arg)]`

Comment: If you have benefited from one of the answers, please accept one of them so others will see it right away :)

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a bit on @EgorSkriptunoff's answer (who needs to change his habit of providing answers in comments ;)): `return (select(math.random(select('#',...)),...))`.

1. `...` provides access to vararg parameter in the function
2. `select('#', ...)` returns the number of parameters passed in that vararg
3. `math.random(select('#',...))` gives you a random number between 1 and the number of passed parameters
4. `select(math.random(select('#',...)),...)` gives you the element with the index specified by that random number from the passed parameters.

The other solution that is using `arg = {...}` gives you almost the same result with one subtle difference related to the number of arguments when `nil` is included as one of the parameters:

```
> function f(...) print(#{...}, select('#', ...)) end
> f(1,2,3)
3   3
> f(1,2,nil)
2   3
> f(1,2,nil,3)
2   4
```

As you can see `select('#',...)` produces more accurate results (this is running LuaJIT, but as far as I remember, Lua 5.1 produces similar results).

Answer (score 1):

```
function randomNumber(...)
    t = {...}
    return t[math.random(1,#t)]
end

print(randomNumber(1, 5, 2, 9))
```

> 1 or 5 or 2 or 9